# Resize ImageView/ImageButton on different screen sizes with same width and height ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have Linearlayout consisting 4 ImageView/ImageButtons. All images have same width and height. I want this layout always fit parent's width and all images scale with the same aspect ratio (width and height):

[image]

I tried this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/item_background"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    // All 4 images are the same 
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the ratio between width and height in land/portrait is not the same. For example in landscape mode, Images are stretched only in x-axis but not y-axis:

[image]

I don't want to go in code for such only UI stuffs and I hope you can help me find a way to do this in XML!

EDIT:

After adding android:scaleType="fitXY" to images I got this:

[image]

and as you can see is not a good solution to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

It will fit the resource in your ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:scaleType="FIT_CENTER"`

Answer (score 0):

that is probably normal since the orientation of your linearlayout is "horizontal".

to solve your problem, you can use the codes answered above.

Comment: I set layout_weight of all images to 1. So this is not a problem.

Comment: I think that your code above is fine in landscape mode, i tried it and its ok. the android:adjustViewBounds="true" preserves the aspect ratio of your image

Answer (score 0):

There is a .9.png image format,developed for android, which may help you solve that problem, here is the link [Draw9patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) from android developer website.